# What evidence confirms or denies the existence of Robin's utility belt?

Tags: dc, batman, costume, robin

Batman's utility belt is a vital component of the crime fighters gear. It would seem to make sense that both of the Caped Crusaders would utilize such a useful addition to their costumes. What canon evidence is there(from any universe) to confirm or deny the existence of Batman's side kick, Robin, of having his own utility belt?

Comment: Rolled back tag edit. There wasn't room for Comics/TV series/movies tags, so I went with Batman, Costume, and Robin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From Batman Issue 203 (as far as I can tell):

[image: utility belts]

Comment: My favorite part in the above diagram is that Batman carried a mini wire recorder.  That issue is from 1968 and magnetic tape recorders were available (just watch *Mission Impossible*) but I guess they figured a wire recorder could better be miniaturized.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_recording

Comment: Can you read all the little labels about the equipment containers on Batman's belt?  Here's my guesses:  1. infrared flashlight, 2. smoke capsule, 3. ----t kit, 4. miniature camera, 5. skeleton keys, 6. tear-gas pellets, 7. t--- power source, 8. miniature wire recorder, 9. bat-rope with automatic reel, 10. laser torch, 11. plastic-explosive grenades, 12. contact lenses assortment.

Comment: @b_jonas, [here](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-S2pwnziXhlA/UXhnpSVS-gI/AAAAAAAB8KU/m_X5e5FfoZo/s640/BatmanUtilityBeltDetailvert_jpg_scaled_500.jpg) is a clearer scan of Batman's belt. Another [here](http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17vfya4tpgwf3jpg/ku-xlarge.jpg), but a different source image.

Comment: @b_jonas you're missing the fingerprint kit and a transistorized power source

Answer (score 4):

It definitely depends on the canon you choose.

### TV Canon

In the 1960s TV series, you can clearly see that Robin is wearing a belt that is nearly identical to the [Batman utility belt](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_HGHxpUhDKRs/SY2i48qnKkI/AAAAAAAACRo/sD1RJngpsEs/s400/suit3.jpg) from the comic series, even down to the vertical capsules. We see him use a grappling line, smoke pellets and a homing transmitter (built into the buckle) on at least one occasion;

[image: Robin Buckle]

### New TV Canon

In "[Young Justice](http://youngjustice.wikia.com/wiki/Utility_belt)", Robin (AKA Nightwing) is described as having a belt containing a grappling gun, numerous Batarangs (regular and explosive), taser, gas pellets and a rebreather

[image]

### In New Comic canon

In [Teen Titans Go](http://teentitans.toonzone.net/index.php?content=bios/robin/index), Robin's Utility Belt is described as containing;

> "*...a variety of projectiles with a vast array of different effects, a
>   retractable bo-staff and a cape made of high-density polymerized
>   titanium that is ten times as strong as steel. From razor-sharp
>   Bird-a-rangs and freeze-disks to complex circuitry capable of hacking
>   the most intricate of portable computer systems*"

[image: Robin Teen Titans]

In [**Batman Chronicles**](http://www.sfcrowsnest.com/articles/books/2007/The-Batman-Chronicles-Volume-2-10877.php) Robin's belt is described as containing a "*conceal[ed] radio set to talk to Batman*"

Comment: That looks *nothing* like Batman's belt in the 60's show. http://www.sideshowtoy.com/assets/products/902080-batman-1960s-tv-series/lg/902080-batman-1966-film-014.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Late to this question, but I happened to find the following evidence in idle re-rereading of old comics just the other day.  From "Teen Titans" Annual #1 (1982), Robin and the Titans are prisoners of aliens.  Here are two of the green chaps discussing Robin's utility belt (and being unimpressed):

[image]

Further visual proof that Robin A) sports a gold and black belt and B) it is a utility belt full of cool toys.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not Cyborg's belt they're referring to? He's the one who has a visible belt in this picture.

Comment: An odd question indeed!  If Cyborg's belt is visible, then it can't very well be the belt in the Gordanian's hand, then can it?

Comment: Ah ok I see....